# How to handle union DOM event types?

Tags: typescript, dom, events

Is it possible to check properly for the event type later so that code below becomes type safe. Since right now the following warnings are raised:

```
  Property 'key' does not exist on type 'ClipboardEvent'
```

```
Property 'clipboardData' does not exist on type 'KeyboardEvent | ClipboardEvent'.
  Property 'clipboardData' does not exist on type 'KeyboardEvent'.ts(2339)
```

**Here is the live copy of the code below in the codesandbox:** 
https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-hugle-i8w1j

```
function cleanInputValue (event: KeyboardEvent | ClipboardEvent): void {
  let incomingValue: string = ``

  switch (true) {
    case typeof event.key !== `undefined`:
      incomingValue = event.key
      break
    case typeof event.clipboardData !== `undefined`:
      incomingValue = event.clipboardData.getData(`text`)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggested a Typescript way - You need to define two functions whose return type is a type predicate: `ClipboardEvent` or `KeyboardEvent`. ([Document](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates))

Check `event` is a ClipboardEvent or not:

```
function isClipboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent | ClipboardEvent): event is ClipboardEvent {
  return (event as ClipboardEvent).clipboardData !== undefined
}
```

again, check `event` is a KeyboardEvent or not:

```
function isKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent | ClipboardEvent): event is KeyboardEvent {
  return (event as KeyboardEvent).key !== undefined
}
```

Now, in `cleanInputValue` function, just check your `event` object and do your task:

```
function cleanInputValue(event: KeyboardEvent | ClipboardEvent): void {
  let incomingValue: string = ``

  if (isClipboardEvent(event) && event.clipboardData) { // clipboardData can be null
    incomingValue = event.clipboardData.getData(`text`)
  } else if (isKeyboardEvent(event)) {
    incomingValue = event.key
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own type guard for this.

```
function cleanInputValue (event: KeyboardEvent | ClipboardEvent): void {
  let incomingValue: string = ``;

  if ('key' in event) {
    incomingValue = event.key
  } else if ('clipboardData' in event && event.clipboardData) {
    incomingValue = event.clipboardData.getData(`text`)
  }
}
```

the `if else` is checking for property `key` on  the union type and narrowing it down to `KeyboardEvent`. Similar for `ClipboardEvent`, the check is narrowing down to a `ClipboardEvent` from the union type you have defined.

[User type guard TS Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types)